# Javascript Display user input

Tags: javascript

How can I display the numbers entered by the user in the textbox after the user has pressed the enter your numbers button. Cant get it to work.

```
function userNumbers()
{
    var usersNumbers = new Array(5)
    for(var count = 0; count <=5; count++){
        usersNumbers[count]=window.prompt("Enter your number "+(count+1)+": " );
    }
    document.lotto.usersNumbers.value = output;
}

 <table width=100% border=0>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <p><input type=button value="Enter your numbers" onClick="userNumbers()"></p>
 Your Numbers: 
 <textarea name="usersNumbers" rows=1 cols=20></textarea>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: What is `output`? That would be your problem. Hint [Array join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<textarea name="usersNumbers" id="textarea" rows=1 cols=20></textarea>
```

```
function userNumbers() {
    var usersNumbers = new Array(5);
    for (var count = 0; count <= 5; count++) {
        usersNumbers[count] = window.prompt("Enter your number " + (count + 1) + ": ");
    }
    document.getElementById("textarea").value = usersNumbers;

    // if using form
    //document.lotto.usersNumbers.value = usersNumbers;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VZnCe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.lotto.usersNumbers.value = userNumbers.join();
```

To give you a comma delimited list of your numbers. You can pass a different separator to `.join` if you want.